# Call terminal command every time page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app made with node.js and I need to write something like this: every time user refreshes the page, `node app.js` command should run in the terminal because I made data fetching in the node and if it won't be reloaded, the data won't change. I've tried to use package.json but it doesn't work. Is there any other way to change the data? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to run a **terminal script** every time the user refreshes **the browser**?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do

Comment: And you are trying to achieve this client-side?

Comment: I think you would need a virtual machine to run a terminal script on from the web - you can do this on AWS but it won't be a very simple solution.

Comment: It's a cryptocurrency Data app and it shows prices and many more details. Its price always changes and that's why I need to re-run "node app.js" to reload the data

Comment: I'm new to the back-end, I don't even know if that's possible :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run the **node app.js** command, again and again, it's a bad approach. Instead of this, You can simply make an API to fetch the data related to cryptocurrency and then make an API call from the frontend and render that fetched data so every time you refresh the page it will make an API call automatically and provide the latest data!